# Unity Limit rotation on camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a FPS controller and I have a problem. The camera rotates fine, but I can rotate in `X` and get upside down. I tried using `Mathf.Clamp` but I could not make it work. This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PJCamera : MonoBehaviour {
    Vector2 mouseLook;
    Vector2 smoothV;
    public float sensibilidad = 5;
    public float smooth = 2;
    GameObject Personaje;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        //Definimos quien es "personaje", el padre de la cámara.
        Personaje = this.transform.parent.gameObject;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        //Cuanto se esta moviendo el raton (md = mouseDelta)
        var md = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y"));

        //Multiplicamos los vectores, el de la posición por la sensibilidad
        md = Vector2.Scale(md, new Vector2(sensibilidad * smooth, sensibilidad * smooth));

        //PRUEBA
        smoothV.x = Mathf.Lerp(smoothV.x, md.x, 1f / smooth);
        smoothV.y = Mathf.Lerp(smoothV.y, md.y, 1f /smooth);
        mouseLook += smoothV;       

        //Hacemos que rote
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-mouseLook.y, Vector3.right);
        Personaje.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(mouseLook.x, Personaje.transform.up);
    }
}
```

Comment: See [Can't Get My Camera To Limit Its Rotation Properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52288641/10223668)

Comment: @EhsanMohammadi  so i have to create a variable for rotation and limit it?

Comment: Indeed. For example, in your code after `mouseLook += smoothV;` line, just add this: `mouseLook = new Vector2(mouseLook.x, Mathf.Clamp(mouseLook.y, -75, 50));`

Comment: Taht worked, thank you

Comment: You're welcome Axel :)

Answer (score 0):

I supose you are trying to give your camera a max rotation when looking down/ up, in this case you can use `Angle(Vector3 from, Vector3 to);` where from is your camera.forward vector and to is your floor. an example here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Angle.html

Solution using clamp:

```
    xRotation= Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, minRoation, maxRotation);
    //of course use local variables here, i give you a loong line just to help you understand.
    Camera.main.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(xRotation, Camera.main.transform.localEulerAngles.y, Camera.main.transform.localEulerAngles.localEulerAngles.z);
```

Generaly, if you want to limit a rotation you should interpolate your transform.rotation between 2 rotations: minRotation and maxRotation. Here is an example from unity docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html